# Установить Web-socket server client

Tags: php

Я использую:

- Windows 10x64;
- OpenSrver.

Я выполнил:
- я скачал вручную архив https://github.com/arthurkushman/php-wss
- я распаковал архив;
- в OpenSrver я создал папку: `phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2\` в папке `c:\openserver\domains\`;
Результат: `c:\openserver\domains\phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2\`;
- я вручную скопировал папку `src` в папку
`c:\openserver\domains\phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2\`;
Папка содержит `c:\openserver\domains\phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2\src\`
Components\
Contracts\
Exceptions\
WebSocketClient.php
WebSocketServer.php
- я открыл консоль OpenSrver;
- я ввёл команду: `cd c:\openserver\domains\phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2\`
- я ввёл команду: `composer require arthurkushman/php-wss`
- результат: в папку C:\OpenServer\domains\phpWssArthurkushmanGithub2 добавились папки и файлы
src\
vendor\
composer.json
composer.lock

**Вопросы.**

1. Как создать и где разместить файл запуска сервера?
2. Как создать и где разместить файл запуска клиента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы серьёзно?

В первом-же примере на github вас не смущают эти 2 строчки?

```
$websocketServer = new WebSocketServer(new ServerHandler(), $config);
$websocketServer->run();
```

Какой ещё WebServer если это Standalone скрипт?

**Дополняю ответ**

Вырезка из bash_history

```
cd PHP
mkdir wsServer
cd wsServer/
composer init
composer require arthurkushman/php-wss
cd src/
vim index.php
php index.php
```

~/PHP/wsServer/src $ cat index.php

```
<?php
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

use WSSC\Contracts\ConnectionContract;
use WSSC\Contracts\WebSocket;
use WSSC\Exceptions\WebSocketException;
use WSSC\WebSocketServer;
use WSSC\Components\ServerConfig;

class ServerHandler extends WebSocket
{
    private $clients = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionContract $conn)
    {
        $this->clients[$conn->getUniqueSocketId()] = $conn;
        echo('Connection opend, clients: ' . count($this->clients) . "\n");
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionContract $recv, $msg)
    {
        echo('Received message:  ' . $msg . "\n");
        $recv->send($msg);
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionContract $conn)
    {
        unset($this->clients[$conn->getUniqueSocketId()]);
        echo('close: ' . print_r($this->clients, 1) . "\n");
        $conn->close();
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionContract $conn, WebSocketException $ex)
    {
        echo 'Error occured: ' . $ex->printStack();
    }

    public function onPing(ConnectionContract $conn, $msg)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onPing() method.
    }

    public function onPong(ConnectionContract $conn, $msg)
    {
    }
}

$config = new ServerConfig();
$config->setClientsPerFork(2500);
$config->setStreamSelectTimeout(2 * 3600);

$webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(new ServerHandler(), $config);
```

Заходим на
https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester

Набераем в адресе

ws://localhost:8000

Тестируем...

*ps: Боже, вы меня в могилу сведете…*

Comment: А вообще мой очень хороший совет - бросайте эту ересь к чертям. Ни один адекватный человек не пишет WebSocket сервер на PHP. Это не тот язык который хорошо работает в режиме сервиса. Если вам нужен простенький сокет сервис, то напишите его на express-ws, если стабильный то на gorilla/websocket. У ноды и go хотя-бы GC работает адекватно... Меньше боли и слёз.

Comment: Не могли бы вы более подробнее описать, что делать?
Я скачал в ручном режиме проект.
И чё?
Где размещать?
Где размещать файлы сервера?
Где размещать файлы клиента?
Как запускать сервер/клиент?

Comment: Это вводить в консоли(Коммандой строке) винды?

Comment: Да, все то-же самое но вместо `vim index.php` надо вводить `notepad index.php`

Comment: Ошибка
`E:\Projects\PHPServers\Php-wssGithub\s01>composer init
"composer" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

Я прошу прощения, я понимаю, что я должен погуглить, но уже закалебался... Каша в голове.

Comment: Пробую через консоль ОпенСервер.
Получаю ошибку `The package name composer require arthurkushman/php-wss is invalid, it should be lowercase and have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name, matching: [a-z0-9_.-]+/[a-z0-9_.-]+`

Картинка https://ibb.co/dfMkrSC